# Doubling "Moving" Verbs （行く and 来る)

Tags: translation, verbs, て-form

I sometimes see moving or directional verbs doubled up, with the first verb in て form. I think my professor mentioned that this just sometimes happens but means the same as if you didn't have the second verb. So essentially the following 2 sentences are the same (both meaning `I went traveling`).

```
旅行に行きました
旅行に行って来ました
```

But is there any nuance difference between the 2?

I might also be wrong. Something tells me this might mean `I went traveling and was still there`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is 「行ってきました」, not 「行って来ました」.  Subsidiary verbs are written in kana.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that was usually the case. But my professor sometimes uses the kanji. Perhaps he is just testing our recognition of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first is simply "I went on a trip".  The second emphasizes the fact that you went an on trip and are (somewhat) recently back now.